# How to grant permissions providing multiple URIs via intent using FileProvider

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to provide multiple URIs via an `Intent` with the help of `FileProvider` from one app to another.

I got it working, when sending only one URI like the following:

```
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
resultIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri,getContentResolver().getType(contentUri));

setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

In my "receiving" app I can continue like this in `onActivityResult`:

```
Uri returnUri = data.getData();
ParcelFileDescriptor mInputPFD = getContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(returnUri, "r");
```

Now I tried sending an `ArrayList` of URIs:

```
resultIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
```

but the granted permission flag only applies to the URI set in `setData()`, so I can't access the URIs from the ArrayList in my receiving app. I read about ClipData as a solution, but I'm unfortunatley forced to go with Min SDK 15.

So my question is, is it a good idea to set the permissions manually in my receiving app with something like

```
context.grantUriPermission("com.example.provider", returnUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

for every URI i would get if I chose the "ArrayList" option and revoke it later on? Can I do this at all? Couldn't every other app access the provider app's private files like that also?

And what package do I have to specify here? My provider app or my receiver app package, since I'm not getting this to work and only get some exception about missing permission.

Any help or hints are appreciated

Comment: "Couldn't every other app access the provider app's private files like that also?" -- no, because you are only granting permissions to whatever app you name in the `grantUriPermission()` call. "And what package do I have to specify here?" -- the receiver. "is it a good idea to set the permissions manually in my receiving app" -- prior to API Level 21, you don't have much of a choice AFAIK.

Comment: thanks for the answers @CommonsWare. I get the following exception `Permission Denial: opening provider [...] that is not exported [...]`. But `android:exported` should be `false` I guess?. Do I have to call `grantUriPermission` in provider or receiver?

Comment: "But android:exported should be false I guess?" -- yes, that's a requirement of `FileProvider`. "Do I have to call grantUriPermission in provider or receiver?" -- IMHO, you call it in your `Activity`, just before calling `startActivity()` to launch a third-party app that will use your `Uri` values. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) for a similar scenario to yours, where I use `grantUriPermission()` for the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` value in an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it.

My problem was, that I called `grantUriPermission()` in my **receiver app** and not in the **provider app** as it should be. So calling the following fixed the permission exceptions:

```
getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission(getCallingPackage(), fileUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```